# Is there a function in numpy to generate a matrix in which each cell represents the time that X appears in Y?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have these arrays

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1]
```

how can I generate the following matrix in an elegant way?

```
matrix = [[0,  0,  0,  0],
          [1,  1,  1,  0],
          [0,  1,  1,  1],
          [1,  2,  0,  0]]
```

The rows represent the X array, and the columns represents the Y array. The values represents how many times the tuple (x,y) appears.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about any numpy method, but you can try this:

```
matrix = np.zeros((4,4))
for ix in zip(x,y):matrix[ix] += 1
```

Output:

```
>>> matrix
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 2., 0., 0.]])
```

Considering `x,y,matrix` are `numpy array`, otherwise if all are lists:

```
matrix = [[0 for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
for ix,iy in zip(x,y):matrix[ix][iy] += 1
```